# How to send server to server binary file using request

Tags: javascript, node.js, request

I'm try to send 'server to server' a file (p12 file), I need to send the file binary.
I'm using request module to send the data in POST method, but its not working, the file is not opened binary, the end point need it this way(binary).

I want to do it similar like 'postman' application when choosing 'binary' in the Body field.

This is the code, I'm using

```
    var request = require('request');
    var fs = require('fs');
        function sendFile(path) {
            var formData = {
                my_file: fs.createReadStream(path)}; 

            request.post({
                url: 'http://myurl.com',
                formData: formData
            },
            function optionalCallback(err, httpResponse, body) {
                if (err) {
                    console.error('upload failed:', err);
                }
                else {
                    console.log('Upload successful!  Server responded with:', body);
                }
            });
        }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is result of `my_file` at endpoint?

Comment: Use the `form-data` module. https://www.npmjs.com/package/form-data#usage

Comment: The module 'request' is using already the module 'form-data' behind its code and 'my_file' its the stream created by 'createReadStream' but its not bunary, 'my_file' its the name 'form-data' module needs.